# Rotate automatically photos taken with Smartphone

Tags: java, android

I'm having some issues with photos taken with the mobile phone camera. When I take a photo and I save it, my mobile phone shows it with the original size, but when I try to open the same photo on my application, it outputs a rotated photo, just like this:

Original photo:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/P7nlfnC.png]

Rotated photo:

[image]

This issue only occurs when I take photos with my mobile phone.

I'm using the following code to select the gallery:

```
private void selectImage() {

        final CharSequence[] options = {"My gallery","Cancel" };

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(PhotosActivity.this);
        builder.setTitle("Add Photo!");
        builder.setItems(options, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                if (options[item].equals("My gallery"))
                {
                    Intent intent = new   Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                    startActivityForResult(intent, 2);

                }
                else if (options[item].equals("Cancel")) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            }
        });
        builder.show();
    }
```

To choose the photo:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
       if (requestCode == 2) {

            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            String[] filePath = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
            Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,filePath, null, null, null);
            c.moveToFirst();
            int columnIndex = c.getColumnIndex(filePath[0]);
            String picturePath = c.getString(columnIndex);
            c.close();
            Bitmap thumbnail = (BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));

            if (thumbnail.getWidth() > thumbnail.getHeight()) {
                Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
                matrix.postRotate(90);
                thumbnail = Bitmap.createBitmap(thumbnail , 0, 0, thumbnail.getWidth(), thumbnail.getHeight(), matrix, true);
            }

            int nh = (int) ( thumbnail.getHeight() * (612.0 / thumbnail.getWidth()) );
            Bitmap scaled = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(thumbnail, 612, nh, true);

            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            scaled.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, stream);

            byte [] byte_arr = stream.toByteArray();
            String image_str = Base64.encodeBytes(byte_arr);

            newtask = new saveImage();
            newtask.execute(image_str,sessionid);

            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Nice!",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    }
}
```

I tried to fix it using the following code, but it doesn't work on landscape photos, I would like to get a code to output the original size.

```
if (thumbnail.getWidth() > thumbnail.getHeight()) {
                    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
                    matrix.postRotate(90);
                    thumbnail = Bitmap.createBitmap(thumbnail , 0, 0, thumbnail.getWidth(), thumbnail.getHeight(), matrix, true);
                }
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you need to query orientation from mediastore (it's ImageColumns.ORIENTATION) .
Try change this line : `matrix.postRotate(90);` to `matrix.postRotate(270);`

Comment: I searched how to get the orientation I found the solution, I used this function here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21085105/get-orientation-of-image-from-mediastore-images-media-data and changed  matrix.postRotate(90); to matrix.postRotate(getExifOrientation(picturePath)); Now is working fine.